# Getting Cannot read property 'mData' of error when trying to render basic table

Tags: datatables

I am trying to render the example table from the datatables tutorial but am getting the following error in my web console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:102)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:102)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.n [as dataTable] (datatables.min.js:95)
    at k.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (datatables.min.js:177)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):92)
    at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

I've seen that the most common cause for this error is the table not being properly formed, but I think what I have is pretty simple and all the tags are there.

My page looks like the following:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#db_data').DataTable();
} );
</script>

<table id="db_data" class="display">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>Row 1 data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is what else could be causing this to happen? I am using this within a django project and this page extends a base.html page which only has navigation bar code and all the necessary CDN includes (js and css), and no mention of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is *thread* a typo, should be **thead**, right???

```
<table id="db_data" class="display">
    <thread> <!-- TYPO -->
```

Comment: YES!! Cant believe I missed that. 2nd pair of eyes always helps though, thanks!